# Webcam keeps on disconnecting and reconnecting

Tags: debian, drivers, chrome, camera, sway

I am on Debian unstable with swaywm. I could also reproduce the same issue on i3.

On running `sudo dmesg` after launching cheese, I get this.
After the initial run, cheese straightaway goes into a dark screen saying "There was an error playing this video".

```
[ 5623.291220] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 25
[ 5623.714000] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd
[ 5623.888575] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=5689, bcdDevice=65.10
[ 5623.888598] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[ 5623.888607] usb 1-5: Product: Integrated Webcam
[ 5623.888615] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: CNFFH36O3624006C3652
[ 5623.888621] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 0x0001
[ 5623.896625] usb 1-5: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Webcam (0bda:5689)
```

This is what dmesg shows after launching google meet:

```
[ 5801.675394] uvcvideo 1-5:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 5802.113321] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
[ 5802.291824] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=5689, bcdDevice=65.10
[ 5802.291844] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[ 5802.291852] usb 1-5: Product: Integrated Webcam
[ 5802.291858] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: CNFFH36O3624006C3652
[ 5802.291864] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 0x0001
[ 5802.301632] usb 1-5: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Webcam (0bda:5689)
[ 5810.273317] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 27
[ 5810.275431] uvcvideo 1-5:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 5810.279429] uvcvideo 1-5:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 5810.283422] uvcvideo 1-5:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
```

The led blinks once and the google meet screen shows "connected to integrated webcam:(0bda:5689) but then the camera cannot be turned on. How do I solve this.

After a system upgrade I have started recieving these messages:

```
[14586.486702] usb 1-5: Failed to query (GET_CUR) UVC control 2 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 2).
[14586.486806] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 8
[14586.486924] usb 1-5: Failed to query (GET_CUR) UVC control 2 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 2).
[14586.486948] usb 1-5: Failed to query (GET_CUR) UVC control 2 on unit 2: -19 (exp. 2).
[14586.486960] usb 1-5: Failed to query (GET_CUR) UVC control 2 on unit 2: -19 (exp. 2).
[14586.486972] usb 1-5: Failed to query (GET_CUR) UVC control 2 on unit 2: -19 (exp. 2).
[14586.486983] usb 1-5: Failed to query (GET_CUR) UVC control 2 on unit 2: -19 (exp. 2).
[14586.487007] usb 1-5: Failed to query (GET_CUR) UVC control 3 on unit 2: -19 (exp. 2).
```